# export TERM before ssh'ing

Tags: colors, ssh, environment-variables, zsh, xterm

I'm using `TERM='xterm-256color'` on my laptop but have to use `TERM='xterm'` on a remote server where `xterm-256color` is not available and breaks down a few things.

So far I can do `export TERM='xterm'; ssh -X 123.45.678.90`, which works fine.  But putting the previous line in an (`zsh`) alias (`alias sshx="export TERM='xterm'; ssh -X 123.45.678.90"`) doesn't seem to work.  E.g., if I insert a `echo $TERM` between the `export` and the `ssh`, doing everything in the command line echoes `xterm`, but the alias gives `xterm-256color`.

And of course, optimally, the `TERM` would be set back to its initial value after the `ssh`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: `.678.` is definitely not a valid IP address part.

Comment: It may be an old zsh bug: with `alias abc='export ABC="$(date)" ; zsh -c "echo \$ABC"'` I do not observe this behavior. Zsh version is 4.3.11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is normally solved by

```
alias sshx='TERM=xterm ssh -X 123.45.67.89'
```

without exporting anything. In other case you will probably have to create a function.

Comment: So how do I know when I have to export?

Comment: @antony It is obvious: you have to export only when you are going to run a sequence of commands. To export only for the time when current function is active you can use `local -x`, thus you could limit the scope where variable is changed: try `export ABC="ghi" ; (){ local -x ABC="def" ; zsh -c 'echo $ABC' } ; zsh -c 'echo $ABC'` (this uses anonymous function, requires at least zsh-4.3.11 if I am not mistaking).

Comment: There is also a patch that will allow you to do something like `alias sshx='() { local -x TERM=xterm ; ssh -X 123.45.67.89 $@ }'`: it will be allowed to pass arguments to anonymous functions (though I suggest to create normal functions in this case).